# How to repeat a the windows form (Tab Function)

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

I am having the form name as "Employee Entry"

User want to open a Employee Entry from in 5 tabs...

For Example

```
When the user open a Employee Entry form, while entering the details at that same time, user again open a employee entry form (2nd Employee entry form show like a new employee entry from with out any details)
```

More Example

```
We can open Google, Yahoo, in one browser (by using Tab Function).
```

How to make this.

Need vb.net code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is WinForms?  You should design your Employee Entry as a User Control.  You can then add a new instance of that control to your Form on each request of a new Employee.  You would most likely have a seperate Employee object that you could pass to each instance of your EmployeeEntry user control.

**EDIT1**

Create a form with a menu strip across the top and a menu item called tsmiNewEmployee.  Add a tab control to the form named tabEntryForms and set its fill style to Dock.  Delete all default tab pages from it.

Add Class:

```
public class EmployeeRecord
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}
```

Add USerControl named EmployeeEntry.  Puts osme Firts/Last name edit cotrols on it, etc.  Add a Save button and a Cancel Button.

```
public partial class EmployeeEntry : UserControl
{

    public event EventHandler Save;

    public event EventHandler Cancel;

    private EmployeeRecord empBeingEdited = null;

    public EmployeeRecord Employee
    {
        get 
        {
            return empBeingEdited; 
        }
        set 
        {   
            empBeingEdited = value;
            if (empBeingEdited == null)
            {
                // clear controls
            }
            else
            { 
                // populate controls with employee values
            }
        }
    }

    public EmployeeEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Save != null)
            Save(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Cancel != null)
            Cancel(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And in your main form that has the tab control:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void tsmiNewEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TabPage tab = new TabPage("New Employee Entry");

        EmployeeEntry empEntry = new EmployeeEntry();
        empEntry.Employee = new EmployeeRecord();

        empEntry.Save += new EventHandler(EmployeeEntry_Save);
        empEntry.Cancel += new EventHandler(EmployeeEntry_Cancel);


        tab.Controls.Add(empEntry);
        empEntry.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        tabEntryForms.TabPages.Add(tab);

    }

    private void EmployeeEntry_Save(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        EmployeeEntry empEntry = source as EmployeeEntry;

        MessageBox.Show("Saved");

        TabPage parentTab = empEntry.Parent as TabPage;
        parentTab.Controls.Remove(empEntry);
        tabEntryForms.Controls.Remove(parentTab);


    }

    private void EmployeeEntry_Cancel(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        EmployeeEntry empEntry = source as EmployeeEntry;

        MessageBox.Show("NOT Saved");

        TabPage parentTab = empEntry.Parent as TabPage;
        parentTab.Controls.Remove(empEntry);
        tabEntryForms.Controls.Remove(parentTab);


    }
}
```

That should get you started.

Comment: @Gopal I'll whip something up